# MQTT Broker does not receive any messages

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I'm trying to connect my Tasmota switch over mqtt. i have installed mosquitto on a virtual machine, heres the configuration:

/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

/etc/mosquitto/acl

```
# weewx readwrite to the loop
user tasmota 
#topic weather/#
```

/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/myconfig.conf

```
allow_anonymous true
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
persistence false 
protocol mqtt
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/acl
```

the service is running, and the port is up

this is the configuration of my switch

[image]

im trying to take a look at messages with

```
mosquitto_sub  -h 10.11.0.106 -t '#'
```

also tried to add user and password, but i dont get any output

i can see in the log, that the connection is established

```
1579896351: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1579896351: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1579896351: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1579896351: New connection from 10.10.0.137 on port 1883.
1579896351: New client connected from 10.10.0.137 as mosqsub|19705-warmachin (c1, k60).
1579896358: Socket error on client mosqsub|19705-warmachin, disconnecting.
1579896358: New connection from 10.10.0.137 on port 1883.
1579896358: New client connected from 10.10.0.137 as mosqsub|19775-warmachin (c1, k60).
1579896361: New connection from 10.11.1.51 on port 1883.
1579896361: New client connected from 10.11.1.51 as DVES_6CA231 (c1, k30, u'tasmota').
1579896361: New connection from 10.11.1.52 on port 1883.
1579896361: New client connected from 10.11.1.52 as DVES_301DDC (c1, k30, u'tasmota').
1579896362: New connection from 10.11.1.54 on port 1883.
1579896362: New client connected from 10.11.1.54 as DVES_350992 (c1, k30, u'tasmota').
```

did i miss something or am i missunderstanding something completely wrong?

please help

Comment: Test without the `password_file` and `acl_file` lines in the `myconfig.conf` file since at the moment you don't any topics enabled for `anonymous` or `tasmota` users

Comment: In fact just remove `myconfig.conf` as it's not doing anything useful.

Comment: well, seems like the acl file was the problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thrashed out in the comments, your ACL file is missing any enabled topics either for the `anonymous` user or the `tasmota` user.

If you enable ACLs you need to define all the topics you want users to be able to access.